# Possibility of connecting two django apps within a django project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am about to build a django project for a web app I am developing. For structural purposes, I want to know if it is possible to have two different apps within a project that communicate with each other like two different things in a single app within a django project. For example:

have two different parts of a django project. users and groups.

I currently have a testing project that has both within the general app of the django project. within the general project I included all parts of project in a single app. I want to know if i can break apart different parts of this project into seperate apps that can communicate with each other (templates, redirects, renders), and how I can connect them or what I need to do to connect them together.

```
example
  -example
    -__init__.py
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
    -wsgi.py
  -general
    -__init__.py
    -admin.py
    -apps.py
    -models.py
    -test.py
    -urls.py
    -views.p
```

THis is what I am thinking of doing

```
example
  -example
     -__init__.py
     -settings.py
     -urls.py
     -wsgi.py
   -users
     -__init__.py
     -admin.py
     -apps.py
     -models.py
     -test.py
     -urls.py
     -views.p
   -groups
     -__init__.py
     -admin.py
     -apps.py
     -models.py
     -test.py
     -urls.py
     -views.p
```

How can i connect the two different projects inthe urls file so I can redirect url's between the two. if possible, what would a redirect look like if I want to go from a url in the users app to a url in a groups app... What would the main urls file look like... in the example folder...

Another question is... are queries going to stay the same or do i need to change how queries are made...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you certainly can have multiple apps communicate with each other in a django project.

example.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^groups/', include('groups.urls')),
]
```

users.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^myurl/$', users.views.myview, name='users_myview'),

]
```

By using the `name` argument with an app identifier such as `users_` you can ensure that your urls can be uniquely identified. In a view you can then refer to it as:

views.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('users_myview',args=())
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read the Django documentation on URL dispatcher. Here is the part referencing [inclusion of other URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

Include urls from apps in the `urlpatterns` in `example.urls`. I also suggest you use namespace argument to avoid confusion.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^', include('groups.urls', namespace='groups')),   
]
```

You then use url syntax `namespace:urlname` in views and templates.

Answer (score 2):

**groups: urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-groups/$', view_1),
    url(r'^fetch-groups/group_id(?P<num>[0-9]+)/$', view_2),
]
```

**users: urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-users/$', group_add_view),
    url(r'^fetch-users/user_id(?P<num>[0-9]+)/$', group_fetch_view),
]
```

**example: url.py** (main url)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from groups.urls import urlpatterns as group_patterns
from users.urls import urlpatterns as user_patterns
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^groups/', include(group_patterns)),
        url(r'^users/', include(user_patterns)),
    ]
```

`/groups/add-groups/` will go to `group_add_view`